# I'm trying to use a modal to call a function that will click a corresponding button on a table cell but it only runs the first record instead

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html-table, onclick

I have a table that displays all values from my 'files' table in a MySQL database, and in one of the columns are the actions you can take regarding the values. One of the actions is to delete the record. My web application is connected to the GDrive API, so I need to authenticate first before deleting the record from GDrive and MySQL. So, I added a modal when clicking the delete button to run the authentication page first and to ask whether to delete or not in the modal. I have two other hidden buttons that should run when a user decides to delete the record, which will do the process of deleting the record from GDrive and MySQL. When a user tries to delete a specific record, it deletes the first record instead of the one selected. I have some JavaScript functions that would click the hidden buttons when the Yes button in the modal has been clicked.

I've tried to check the problem by manually deleting the record through the two hidden buttons with the functions for deleting it, and it works fine. However, when I use the modal, it only deletes the first and sometimes all the records. Here is my code:

```
<td>
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $rows['file_viewLink'];?>'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> View</button>
   <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $rows['file_downloadLink'];?>'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> Download</button>
   <button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete" type="button" onclick="handleAuthClick()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove</button>
   <button class="remove-drive" id="removeFromDrive" type="button" onclick="deleteFile('<?php echo $rows['file_id'];?>')" hidden></button>
   <button class="remove-db" id="removeDb" type="button" onclick="removeFromDb('<?php echo $rows['file_id'];?>')" hidden></button>
</td>
```

Here's the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_remove" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">System</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4 class="text-danger">Are you sure you want to remove this file?</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">No</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteFromDrive();delayDelete();" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then there is the javascript:

```
<script>
   function deleteFromDrive() {
      document.getElementById('removeFromDrive').click();
   }

   function deleteClick() {
      document.getElementById('removeDb').click();
   }

   function delayDelete() {
      setTimeout("deleteClick()", 5000);
      $('#modal_remove').modal('hide');
   }
</script>
```

Then I have an Ajax request for deletion in GDrive and MySQL, which works fine and doesn't have the problem:

```
async function deleteFile(fileId) {

    const accessToken = gapi.client.getToken().access_token;

    const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + fileId;
    return await fetch(url, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function (value) {
        console.log(value);
    });
}

function removeFromDb(fileId) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'delete.php',
        data: { 'fileId': fileId },
        success: function(response) {
            // Handle the response from delete.php
            console.log(response);
            alert("The file has been deleted successfully.");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // Handle errors
            console.error(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Please help me out. It's for my thesis project for graduation, and I was almost done with it when I encountered this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: are your element `id`s unique - the fact that you are using `id` in a `<td>` suggests not

Comment: No, the ids are not unique. Is there another way to fix that? I tried using the class or name for the javascript function but for some reason it won't recognize it as a function.

Comment: Create an `auto_increment` data field in your db table and it will generate unique id for each record

Comment: no idea if that's the issue to be honest, but it is a red flag - as to how you fix it ... you have `'file_id'` so ... as for your error when using class instead, you're probably doing it wrong

Comment: The records already has auto_increment but that's not the problem I'm having, it recognizes the 'file_id' for each record but when I use the modal to call on the functions, the only 'file_id' it recognizes is the first record's that's why it's the one getting deleted instead of the specific one. I'm sorry if it's confusing, I don't know if I explained it correctly.

Comment: You need to use a custom data attribute like data-id which holds the id of the file which you use with javascript to pass to the function to do the delete of a file with that id

Comment: I added a data-id to the modal already. How can I make that work? Also, are there any web hosting platforms I can use to host my website? My website has php pages instead of just html and uses APIs and js. Thank you!